# how install qt4-no-webkit in macOS Sierra

Tags: macos, qt, installation, ros

I'm trying install ROS indigo in macOS Sierra.

However I met a big trouble on it.

I searched a lot and from here(https://github.com/mikepurvis/ros-install-osx/issues/63) I found the reason why I cannot install indigo in Sierra successfully.

indigo needs qt4. but Sierra just has qt5.

therefore, I installed qt4 by following this question([Python PyQt on macOS Sierra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39821177/python-pyqt-on-macos-sierra))

```
brew tap cartr/qt4
brew tap-pin cartr/qt4
brew install qt
brew install pyside
```

when I checked qt with command:

> brew info qt

it showed:

```
cartr/qt4/qt: stable 4.8.7 (bottled), HEAD
Cross-platform application and UI framework
https://www.qt.io/
/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.7_3 (2,720 files, 109.4MB) *
  Poured from bottle on 2017-03-21 at 10:28:32
From: https://github.com/cartr/homebrew-qt4/blob/master/qt.rb
==> Dependencies
Required: openssl ✔
Optional: dbus ✘, mysql ✘, postgresql ✘
==> Requirements
Build: git ✔
==> Options
--with-dbus
    Build with dbus support
--with-docs
    Build documentation
--with-mysql
    Build with mysql support
--with-postgresql
    Build with postgresql support
--with-qt3support
    Build with deprecated Qt3Support module support
--without-webkit
    Build without QtWebKit module
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
==> Caveats
We agreed to the Qt opensource license for you.
If this is unacceptable you should uninstall.

Qt Designer no longer picks up changes to the QT_PLUGIN_PATH environment
variable as it was tweaked to search for plug-ins provided by formulae in
  /usr/local/lib/qt4/plugins

Phonon is not supported on macOS Sierra or with Xcode 8.
```

then, I tried to install ROS again. it warned:

```
==> Installing gazebo1 from osrf/simulation
qt4-no-webkit: This formula either does not compile or function as expected on macOS
versions newer than El Capitan due to an upstream incompatibility.
```

could anyone help me solve this problem?

I appreciate you help.

thanks advance

Comment: Well, the error message clearly reads that is an upstream incompatibility. Which makes me believe it is a known bug. Qt has an opensource license but it is being developed and maintained a commercial company, so they are probably the only ones able to fix this. Best guess: email them. Hope you'll be able to find a work-around though..

Comment: thanks@SB87, I'll try

Comment: how is the latest news? @HOWE Can you interprete this "# Qt4 is dead upstream. We backported a build fix for 10.11 but do not
  # intend to keep rescuing it forever, including for macOS 10.12. Homebrew will
  # be migrating to Qt5 as widely as possible, which remains supported upstream.
" said https://github.com/osrf/homebrew-simulation/blob/master/qt4-no-webkit.rb