# Install PyQt4 on a macOS Sierra 10.12.6

Tags: python, pyqt4

No matter what I have done in the last 2 weeks, I am unable to use PyQt4 library with Pycharm. This happens while I try to activate python alone or with QtDesigner integration. 
I receive: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt4'"  all the time. whether from Pycharm while I try to add an interpreter, PyQt4 to my python project, or whether I run shell commands like "python 3.py".

I have read and tried everything in my power, concerning this issue. 
Can someone, experienced, try to explain clearly, thoroughly and exactly, how to solve this issue ? I wish to execute python commands without this error.
Thanks in advance, 
Daniel

Comment: you'll need to show some code.  it sounds like you are having the problem regardless of whether of not you use pycharm.

Comment: With pleasure : i go to the terminal to the same dir that the py file exists. in this file I have : from PyQt4 import *

print('hi')  when i run in the terminal python 3.py . i get this result :  File "3.py", line 1, in <module>
    from PyQt4 import *
ImportError: No module named PyQt4

Comment: PyQt4 has to do with the backend for plotting.  What are you trying to do with it?   You may be able to us another backend.

Comment: I try to use PyQt4 modules while I am Pythoning. and why ? I have built something with Qtdesigner so I can transform it to Phython code (user interface desktop applet)

Comment: Possible duplicate [python-pyqt-on-macos-sierra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39821177/python-pyqt-on-macos-sierra).   note PyQt5 rather than is now recommended