# Reason: Incompatible library version: QtWidgets.so requires version 5.10.0 or later, but QtWidgets provides version 5.7.0

Tags: python, pyqt, qtwidgets, pyforms

I'm a complete newbie when it comes to Python programming and I would like to dive myself into Python GUI application programming and have been trying to get **Pyforms** to work on my **Macbook 12" 2017 running macOS High Sierra 10.13.3**

I followed the instruction listed on pyforms documentation website [**right here**](https://pyforms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#installation) on how to install it.

I installed python on my mac with [this tutorial right here](https://joernhees.de/blog/2014/02/25/scientific-python-on-mac-os-x-10-9-with-homebrew/):

For the last 20 hours or so I've been dumbfounded by this error that I kept getting whenever I tried to run the **example.py** that they provided on [this page](https://pyforms.readthedocs.io/en/v3.0/getting-started/the-basic/)

The error on the terminal whenever I tried to execute `python example.py` is:

> Reason: Incompatible library version: QtWidgets.so requires version 5.10.0 or later, but QtWidgets provides version 5.7.0

I don't understand why this happens as I've made sure to install PyQt5 using `pip install pyqt5` and it installed the latest 5.10.0 version.

I'm a total beginner when it comes to this, I tried to google a bunch of stuff and followed multiple tutorials to no avail. So now I have to turn to the professionals in stackoverflow.

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: try [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39821177/python-pyqt-on-macos-sierra] which is an almost similar question

Comment: @And3r50n1, already tried mate. I have have SIP installed as well and I have exported PYTHONPATH into my .bash_profile. None of it worked, still got the same error. Thanks for the help though

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? i am stuck trying to resolve the same

Comment: @SpaceBear hi there mate, wow this was a long time ago hahaha. Errr unfortunately I didn’t find any solution to this one mate 

Comment: damn, i've been stuck on this for a while. it's crazy