# Cannot install pyqt5-tools - 'Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyqt5-tools'

Tags: python, pip, pyqt5

I try to install pyqt5-tools like this:

```
pip install pyqt5-tools
```

and the resulting out put is:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyqt5-tools (from versions: none)

ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyqt5-tools
```

I need to download pyqt5-tools because I am trying to learn how to make GUIs with PyQt (I am a beginner programmer).

I have tried downloading different packages but anything related to PyQt has failed... It happens on both my Mac and Ubuntu machine.

I have checked that the packages are available on PyPI and literally copy-pasted the install command from the website into the terminal to make sure that I did not do it wrong.

Comment: if you have python3.10 it is not working for me too. If I install additional python 3.9 and with 3.9 when i created venv, in that 3.9 venv if i install pyqt5-tools it installed well.

Comment: I have done all of the following and it still doesnt want to install. Ive tried using 3.9 and 3.12.

Answer (score 10):

Assuming you are installing that for qtdesigner. You can install it by package manager. I've installed it on my Debian machine

```
sudo apt install pyqt5-dev-tools pyqt5-dev
```

And you can find QtDesigner in

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/designer
```

Comment: Me personally I'm using the `qttools5-dev-tools` package (available in Debian repos). It installs Qt 5 Designer, Qt 5 Assistant and Qt 5 Linguist and additionally creates shortcuts for launching.

Answer (score 9):

If you are on windows use `pip install PyQt5Designer` instead.

Answer (score 7):

You can download [pyside2](https://pypi.org/project/PySide2/) it includes almost everything in pyqt5-tools; pyqt5, pyuic5 and the qdesigner

```
pip install PySide2
```

Answer (score 3):

pyqt5-tools is only available for Windows as seen on their site: https://pypi.org/project/pyqt5-tools/

Try an alternative such as QT-creator for Mac: https://www.qt.io/download

This post strongly supports using Homebrew: [Python PyQt on macOS Sierra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39821177/python-pyqt-on-macos-sierra)

Comment: Ah. Thank you! Do you know how to convert .ui to .py with QT Creator?

Comment: No, but someone does:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18429452/convert-pyqt-ui-to-python

Comment: I have the same problem in Windows. When trying to install pyqt5-tools it says could not find a version that satisfies the requirements. I was able to install PySide2 without problems though. What's going on with pyqt5-tools? thanks

Comment: The link you posted has the following text "Both Windows and Linux are supported". It does not fully support MacOS, but Linux is OK.

Answer (score 3):

At first, if you are using python v3.10, probably, it won't work well.
when I have this error I uninstall python.
then install the python v3.9. it works better as it is older than v3.10

Comment: Switching to 3.9 did the trick for me, I did not uninstall 3.10 but installed 3.9 next to 3.10 and I created a virtual environment using 3.9 for this

Comment: wow, is it working well?

Answer (score 3):

**Best Solution I found**

If you try to download `pyqt5-tools` it's not going to work with **`python v.3.10.x`**. But if you want to download it correctly you should try this solution because it works for me.

1. Install `PyQt5`:

```
pip install pyqt5
```

2. Install `PyQt5Designer`:

```
pip install PyQt5Designer
```

Then you should Find the `Qt Designer`, under the name **`designer.exe`**:

```bash
C:\...\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages\QtDesigner\designer.exe
```

Note that the installation path of python may be different for you, to find yours, try this on your Python interpreter, type the following commands:

```py
>>> import os, sys
>>> os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
'C:\\path-to-your-python-installation\\Python\\Python310'
```

Then you should find the `QtDesigner` after that path in for of:

```
C:\...\Python310\Lib\site-packages\QtDesigner\designer.exe
```

Just click on it, and pin it to your start or taskbar.

Or Simply if you want to download it directly as `.exe`, But I'm not sure if this can miss some pyqt5-tools:

[Qt Designer Download](https://build-system.fman.io/qt-designer-download)

Answer (score -1):

Go to Your python installation folder and find this followings:
Go here
`Lib\site-packages\qt5_applications\Qt\bin`
and you will find your qt designer

Comment: The question is about Mac and Linux, not windows.

Answer (score -1):

you should change your version from the newest version to a slightly old one, for example, 3.10 to 3.8 .
it is a normal thing when a new version is released, keep in mind that you have to update pip (using: python -m pip install --upgrade pip )