# Error while trying to install PyQt designer on Macbook

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have installed PyQt5 on my Macbook, however when I try and run the command to install the tools, I am getting an error as follows:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyqt5-plugins<5.15.2.3,>=5.15.2.2 (from pyqt5-tools) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyqt5-plugins<5.15.2.3,>=5.15.2.2 (from pyqt5-tools)
```

Here is the full input and output:

```
(base) _-Air:Chess-Final _$ pip3.7 install pyqt5-tools
Collecting pyqt5-tools
  Using cached pyqt5_tools-5.15.2.3.0.2-py3-none-any.whl (28 kB)
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyqt5-plugins<5.15.2.3,>=5.15.2.2 (from pyqt5-tools) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyqt5-plugins<5.15.2.3,>=5.15.2.2 (from pyqt5-tools)
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2.3; however, version 20.3.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/usr/local/bin/python3.7 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

I have tried downloading QT designer from its website, but since I want it for personal use, I am not able to get it (it requires company information)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out that pyqt5-tools is only available for Windows as seen on their site: https://pypi.org/project/pyqt5-tools/

Try an alternative such as QT-creator for Mac: https://www.qt.io/download

This post strongly supports using Homebrew: [Python PyQt on macOS Sierra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39821177/python-pyqt-on-macos-sierra)